# "C:\ ..." Was unexpected at this time

Tags: batch-file

I am writing a short batch script for my game engine and it is to locate the computer's java.exe (searches for JRE).  It is then to use it to start the initial python script.

My problem is when I run this script - it responds with:

```
"Java\jre7\bin\java.exe" was unexpected at this time.
```

Any advice and/or solutions will be appreciated.

```
@echo off
color 0e
title py console
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\"
if exists "Java\jre7\bin\java.exe" (
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\"
start "" "java.exe" -jar "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\RPG Engine\jython.jar" "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\RPG Engine\init.py"
)
pause >nul
```

Answer (score 3):

It's `exist`, not `exists`:

```
if exist "Java\jre7\bin\java.exe" (
    ...
```